# Extract values from mySQL database into Excel using VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have installed the mySQL server on my computer and created the Database called `Sales` consisting of one table called `Orders`. You can also find the table in the `SQL fiddle` [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b64d10):

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID INT,
    Customer VARCHAR(255),
    Revenue VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Orders
(OrderID, Customer, Revenue)
VALUES 
("1", "Customer A","400"),
("2", "Customer A","200"),
("3", "Customer B","600"),
("4", "Customer C","150"),
("5", "Customer C","800"),
("6", "Customer C","300");
```

Then I created an Excel file and activated `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library`. 
Now I wanted to connect to the Database above and extract data from it using the following `VBA` script:

```
Sub ConnectDB()
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=Sales; UID=root; PWD=mypassword; OPTION=3"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM sales.orders;")
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = rs

End Sub
```

However, when I run this VBA I get `runtime error 3704`. As far as I can tell this error is probably caused by these lines:

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM sales.orders;")
```

because if I delete them the VBA runs without the error.

What do I need to change in my code to extract the Data from the mySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

your connection is not open

try this

```
    Sub ConnectDB()
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=Sales; UID=root; PWD=mypassword; OPTION=3"
conn.open
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM sales.orders;")
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = rs

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. When I try it I get runtime error -2147467259 (80004005)

Comment: `Execute` is for updating the database, not for returning a recordset.

Comment: @braX , this code "conn.open + conn.execute " works perfectly on my side (I have another DB thus another connection string).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Execute` - that is for running a command on the database, not for returning a recordset.

```
Sub ConnectDB()
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=Sales; UID=root; PWD=mypassword; OPTION=3"
    conn.Open

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM sales.orders;", conn
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = rs
End Sub
```

And if your string fields return what looks like garbage, you are going to have to do a little more than that too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to run it but also get runtime error -2147467259 (80004005). When I went through the code this error appears on the line conn.Open.

Comment: Is there some setting I might need to change to make the conn.Open work?

Comment: I am using Office 2007. Is there a specific (old) string connection necessary for it?

Comment: Your connection string is probably the issue if you cannot even open a connection to the database with it, so it wouldnt matter what version of Office you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
```

Then

```
    Private Sub ConnectDB()
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim str As String

str = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
      "SERVER=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX replace with your IP address" & ";" & _
      "PORT=replace with the port you are using, usually 3306" & ";" & _
      "DATABASE=replace with the name of your databese" & ";" & _
      "USER=replace with the username you are using to connetc yourself to the databes" & ";" & _
      "PASSWORD=replace with password you are using to connect to the databse" & ";" & _
      "Option=3"


oConn.Open str
End Sub
```

And Finally

```
    Sub InsertData()

Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset

Dim Requete As String

    Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Call ConnectDB
    Requete = "SELECT * FROM sales.orders;" 
    Rs.Open Requete, oConnect, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic


    End With
    oConnect.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Excel 2000 or newer there is a surprisingly easy way to do this, and to even get the MySQL column names.

```
Public Sub insert_data()
    Dim dbConn As New ADODB.Connection, rs As New ADODB.Recordset, sql As String
    Dim ws As New Excel.Worksheet, cCtr As Long, numFields As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    dbConn.ConnectionString = "[put your connection string here]"
    dbConn.Open

    sql = "SELECT * FROM sales.orders;"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = dbConn.Execute(sql, , adCmdText)
    
    With ws
        ' Get the number of columns:
        numFields = rs.Fields.Count
        
        ' Put the column names into the first row of your worksheet:
        For cCtr = 1 To numFields
            .Cells(1, cCtr).Value = rs.Fields(cCtr - 1).name
        Next cCtr
        
        ' Put all the recordset data into your worksheet,
        ' starting from the worksheet's second row:
        .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
    
    dbConn.Close
End Sub
```